# Regex for fun - Match words with a number of characters equal to 2^n

Tags: regex

**Hey there !**
I am always looking for reflexion subjects about regex. I would like a regex that matches every words that contain 2^n characters in a list of words (where n is a natural number).
To make it simple, let's say a word is just a sequence of `o`
Let's also say the list is composed by words followed by the number of characters they contain and separated by spaces
Of course you can't use these numbers, it is for reading purpose !
For exemple in the list :
`o (1) ooo (3) oooooo (6) oooo (4) ooooooooo (9) oo (2) oooooooooooo (12) oooooooo (8)`
We should have the following matches :

```
matches : 'o', 'oo', 'oooo', 'oooooooo'
```

Your regex must however respect some rules :

- You cannot use recursion
- You cannot use any feature specific to a language (or a few languages)

If you manage to find one (or a trick) that works in javascript, it would be awesome (I don't think this is possible, though) !
Of course, it doesn't need to work with javascript.
Solving the problem is not the point here, I am only interested in **how** to solve it !
**Edit :**
Sadly, nobody found anything I was looking for. The question is still opened to answers, there must be good ones !
By the way, here is what I came up with, even if there should be better than that :
`\b(?:o|(?:(?(1)\1|o)(?=((?(1)\1\1|o))))+\1)\b`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PCB4x4/1)

Comment: Just to clarify: *"You cannot use any feature specific to a language (or a few languages)"*, but *"a trick that works in javascript"* is ok?

Comment: Yeah, it's just that javascript's regex is a bit poor, so I don't think it is possible ^^

Comment: However, that's a specific case, if someone finds a javascript regex without any trick, it would be even more awesome ! ;) Edit : maybe the end is a bit unclear, I will clarify this ^^

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tzAg8D/1 though this obviously is a limited scope ;) - so NAA.

Comment: Well... That is... violent ! xD Even if it won't work for any n, you might have some ^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh nice, tg=hat was exactly what I was looking for, thanks ! I'll try over there )

Comment: I revise my comment : This is exactly the kind of site I was looking for to learn regex, but this is absolutely not the place to post this current question, as it is clearly not a puzzle nor a codegolf challenge, but a real regex question.

Answer (score 2):

I know, you said *no recursion*, but just for the record:

```
\b(?:o|(o(?1)?o))\b
```

[Test it on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/99YQCR/1)

Let's break it down (so I can finally understand why it works as intended)!
Ignore whitespace.

```
\b (?: o | ( o (?1)? o ) ) \b
\b                         \b # Word boundaries. Boring.
   (?: o |               )    # Just so it matches a single o, too.
           ( o (?1)? o )      # Now that's the interesting part.
           (           )      # Capture group 1
             o       o        # Matches an o each at the start and the end of the group
                              # -> the pattern matches from the outside to the inside.
               (?1)?          # Again the pattern of group 1, or nothing.
                              # -> Again one 'o' at the start and one at the end. Or nothing.
```

To be honest, I don't know why it does not match `oooooo` (6) with <s>three</s> two recursions.

Edit: [I asked a new question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889664/how-exactly-do-recursive-regexes-work)

Comment: Nice one ! But it does make it too easy, that's why I do not want recursion ^^

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how exactly that works... :)

Comment: You mean, the recursive one ?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the answer. I don't know why it doesn't match 6 characters.

Comment: Here is how I see it (ignore the "[]", it's just to show what has been inserted) : 1st "loop" -> `[o(?1)?o]` is captured, 2nd "loop" `o[o(?1)?o]o` is captured, 3rd "loop" -> `oo[oo(?1)?oo]oo`

Comment: Each time you replace (?1) by the content of the precedent loop (yeah I know there is no loop, but I don't know how to call it ^^)

Comment: Must be so, apparently. But: 1. I read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) as "*pattern* is repeated", not *contents*. 2: The contents of group 1 is not yet completed when recursion takes place. But the result is clear.

Comment: It's the expression inside the capturing group that is repeated. And as the capturing group updates itself at each loop, the expression repeated does as well !

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work on most regex engines that support backreferences for capture groups 1 to 9.
But it can only capture up to 2^11=2048 o's

```
\bo{1,2}\b|\b(((((((((o{4})\9?)\8?)\7?)\6?)\5?)\4?)\3?)\2?)\1?\b
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/ouPEgk/2)

Or... we can just hardcode the 2^n numbers ;)

```
\b(?:o|oo|o{4}|o{8}|o{16}|o{32}|o{64}|o{128}|o{256}|o{512}|o{1024}|o{2048})\b
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. What you get here are `o` and sequences of 2n `o`, which is not 2^n `o` ;)

Comment: Haha no problem ! Your regex almost works indeed, but I want one that works for any power of 2 !

Comment: Yes, but without recursion it does seem impossible to create a generic regex that would work on almost any regex engine. But you probably already realised that.

Comment: I know it is possible, because I did it ;) But I'm using conditionals, so it's not generic at all... I don't post it yet, because I'm waiting for some smart mind to find an awesome solution I couldn't even think about ^^

Answer (score 0):

There's a proof that you can't do that with regular languages or even a context free grammar here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/show-that-0i-where-i-is-a-power-of-2-is-not-context-free

So I believe that a regex without back references or any complex extensions is impossible to create.

Regular expressions with backreferences are NP-complete according to this http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html, so back references should be enough to make the regex work.

Comment: Of course that is impossible with a *regular* regular expression. Anything that needs to use any kind of memory can obviously not be regular. However, when I talk about regular expression, I am using the abuse of language, like almost *everyone* does today.

Comment: The second article is very interesting though, thanks for sharing it !

Comment: You said "You cannot use recursion". If you meant back references, than the task is impossible

Comment: By *recursion* I meant recursive regex (like ones containing (?R), or (?1) for instance)