# How exactly does this recursive regex work?

Tags: regex, recursion, pcre, regex-group, regex-recursion

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875776/regex-for-fun-match-words-with-a-number-of-characters-equal-to-2n).

Have a look at this pattern:

```
(o(?1)?o)
```

It matches any sequence of `o` with a length of 2<sup>n</sup>, with n ≥ 1.
[It works, see regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4cvSvM/1) (word boundaries added for better demonstration).
The question is: **Why?**

In the following, the description of a string (match or not) will simply be a bolded number or a bolded term that describes the length, like **2<sup>n</sup>**.

Broken down (with added whitespaces):

```
( o (?1)? o )
(           ) # Capture group 1
  o       o   # Matches an o each at the start and the end of the group
              # -> the pattern matches from the outside to the inside.
    (?1)?     # Again the regex of group 1, or nothing.
              # -> Again one 'o' at the start and one at the end. Or nothing.
```

I don't understand why this doesn't match **2n**, but **2<sup>n</sup>**, because I would describe the pattern as *an undefined number of `o o`, stacked into each other.

**Visualization:**

No recursion, **2** is a match:

```
oo
```

One recursion, **4** is a match:

```
o  o
 oo
```

So far, so easy.

Two recursions. Obviously wrong because the pattern does not match **6**:

```
o    o
 o  o
  oo
```

But why? It seems to fit the pattern.

I conclude that it's not simply the plain pattern that is repeated because otherwise **6** would have to match.

But according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

> `(?P<name>[abc])(?1)(?P>name)` matches three letters like `(?P<name>[abc])[abc][abc]` does.

and

> `[abc])(?1){3}` [...] is equivalent to `([abc])[abc]{3}`

So it does seem to simply rematch the regex code without an information about the previous match of the capture group.

Can someone explain and maybe visualize why this pattern matches **2<sup>n</sup>** and nothing else?

**Edit:**

It was mentioned in the comments:

> I doubt that referencing a capture group inside of itself is actually a supported case.

[regular-expressions.info does mention the technique:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html)

> If you place a call inside the group that it calls, you'll have a recursive capturing group.

Comment: You understand recursion correctly. Word boundaries baffle you here. [Look here](https://regex101.com/r/SJ3SF3/1), 6 `o`s are matched just fine.

Comment: That's interesting. You're right, that baffles me. Where's the difference between 6, 8, 12, and 16 in regards to word boundaries? I'll edit the question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understand recursion correctly. Word boundaries baffle you here. The `\b` around the pattern require the regex engine to only match the string if it is not preceded and followed with word chars.

See how the recursion goes here:

```
( o      (?1)?         o )  => oo
```

`(?1)` is then replaced with `(o(?1)?o)`:

```
( o   (?>o(?1)?o)?     o )  => oo or oooo
```

Then again:

```
(o (?>o(?>o(?1)?o)?o)?  o) => oo, oooo, oooooo
```

See the [regex demo without word boundaries](https://regex101.com/r/SJ3SF3/2).

*Why adding `(?>...)` in the example above?* [Each recursion level in PHP recursive regexes is *atomic*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html#atomiclevels), *unlike Perl*, and once a preceding level fails, the engine does not go back to the following one.

When you add word boundaries, the first `o` and last `o` matched cannot have any other word chars before/after. So, `ooo` [won't match](https://regex101.com/r/4R8x4Z/1) then.

See [**Recursive Regular Expressions**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) explained step by step and [**Word Boundary: `\b`**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) at rexegg.com, too.

> Why does `oooooo` not get matched as a whole but as `oooo` and `oo`?

Again, each recursion level is atomic. `oooooo` is matched like this:

- `(o(?1)?o)` matches the first `o`
- `(?1)?` gets expanded and the pattern is now `(o(?>o(?1)?o)?o)` and it matches the second `o` in the input
- It goes on until `(o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?1)?o)?o)?o)?o)?o)?o)?o)` that does not match the input any longer, backtracking happens, we go to the 6th level,
- The whole 6th recursion level also fails since it cannot match the necessary amount of `o`s
- This goes on until the level that can match the necessary amount of `o`s.

See the [regex debugger](https://regex101.com/r/pZPmjF/1/debugger):

[image]

Comment: I still struggle to understand, why 6 `o`s is matched as 4 + 2, 7 `o`s is matched as 6?

Comment: @SebastianProske: Check [this debugger](https://regex101.com/r/nMqIaT/1/debugger) - the first `o` (on the left side of the recursion construct) grabs all the `o`s in the input string. Then each final `o` must be accommodated for *on each depth level*. The engine backtracks within the main subpattern this way.

Comment: @SebastianProske: And  it also has got to do with the fact that [each recursion depth is atomic](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html): since the first `o` before `(?1)` matched all the `o`s in the string, then there is no place for the final `o` to match as there is no more text for the last but one recursion level.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it all figured out. I have added the steps I took to realize as an answer - but yours definitely deserves my +1.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less a follow up of Wiktors answer - even after removing the word boundaries, I had a hard time figuring out why `oooooo` (6) gets matched as `oooo` and `oo`, while `ooooooo` (7) gets matched as `oooooo`.

Here is how it works in detail:

When expanding the recursive pattern, the inner recursions are atomic. With our pattern we can unroll it to

```
(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>oo)?o)?o)?o)?o)
```

(In the actual pattern this get's unrolled once more, but that doesn't change the explanation)

And here is how the strings are matched - first `oooooo` (6)

```
(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>oo)?o)?o)?o)?o)
o   |ooooo                          <- first o gets matched by first atomic group
o   o   |oooo                       <- second o accordingly
o   o   o   |ooo                    <- third o accordingly
o   o   o   o   |oo                 <- fourth o accordingly
o   o   o   o   oo|                 <- fifth/sixth o by the innermost atomic group
                     ^              <- there is no more o to match, so backtracking starts - innermost ag is not matched, cursor positioned after 4th character
o   o   o   o   xx   o   |o         <- fifth o matches, fourth ag is successfully matched (thus no backtracking into it)
o   o   o   o   xx   o   o|         <- sixth o matches, third ag is successfully matched (thus no backtracking into it)
                           ^        <- no more o, backtracking again - third ag can't be backtracked in, so backtracking into second ag (with matching 3rd 0 times)
o   o                      |oo<oo   <- third and fourth o close second and first atomic group -> match returned  (4 os)
```

And now `ooooooo` (7)

```
(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>o(?>oo)?o)?o)?o)?o)    
o   |oooooo                         <- first o gets matched by first atomic group
o   o   |ooooo                      <- second o accordingly
o   o   o   |oooo                   <- third o accordingly
o   o   o   o   |ooo                <- fourth o accordingly
o   o   o   o   oo|o                <- fifth/sixth o by the innermost atomic group
o   o   o   o   oo  o|              <- fourth ag is matched successfully (thus no backtracking into it)
                         ^          <- no more o, so backtracking starts here, no backtracking into fourth ag, try again 3rd
o   o   o                |ooo<o     <- 3rd ag can be closed, as well as second and first -> match returned (6 os)
```