# Reuse the same prefix to find the next match if any

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-re

I have this kind of strings:

```
string = '
something .... something else ...
url="/transfer/packages/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/connectors/68f74d66-ca3d-4272-9b59-4f737946b3f7/something/138bb190-3b12-4855-88e2-0d1cdf46aeb5/...../...../...../...../...."
other things ...
'
```

without any CR/LF, it is all on one line.

I want to create a regex which:

- if and only if the url starts with `/transfer/packages/`
- captures each subsequent GUID
- until the end of the quoted string `"`
- the number of GUID to be found is unknown and is at least one

So far I wrote:

```
\/transfer\/packages\/[^"]*([A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12})"
```

but it only capture the LAST guid. I need some how to reuse the prefix `/transfer/packages/` and keep matching eagerly expanding the search each time without moving on from the prefix.

Comment: So you want to match each one of the GUIDs as long as they are in a string that starts with `/transfer/packages/`, yeah?

Comment: You're right. (Later on in the same string there may be others url="/transfer/package/..." and they must be captured as well, but I don't think this is relevant because if so it is entirely another piece of the string)

Comment: What app are you using? Btw, `-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}` is better written `(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}){3}` maybe?

Comment: And instead of trying to do this in one go, maybe use two steps. First check if your string starts with your requirement, then use a pattern like `[A-Za-z0-9]{8}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}` to find all substrings of interest.

Comment: Yes that solves the problem indeed. However I'm curious whether this can be done in a single passage!

Comment: What is the language? Sure it can be done, but not in all languages.

Comment: I'm using the `re` library in python3.6, however shouldn't this be language independent?

Comment: Then it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports infinite length quantifiers in the lookbehind:

```
(?<=url="/transfer/packages/[^\r\n"]*)[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}(?=[^\r\n"]*")
```

Example [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dbo2Fi/1) (with another engine selected for demo purpose) or see a [Python demo](https://rextester.com/CYRJ20855)

---

Another option is to first match the line that has `url="/transfer/packages/`followed by a guid and match until the next double quote.

Then you could use for example [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get all the guids.

```
"/transfer/packages/[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}[^"\r\n]*"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2seU2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rJbrcD)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r'"/transfer/packages/[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}[^"\r\n]*"'
test_str = ("something .... something else ...\n"
    "url=\"/transfer/packages/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/connectors/68f74d66-ca3d-4272-9b59-4f737946b3f7/something/138bb190-3b12-4855-88e2-0d1cdf46aeb5/...../...../...../...../....\"\n"
    "other things ...\n\n"
    "68f74d66-ca3d-4272-9b59-4f737946b300")

for str in re.findall(regex, test_str):
    print(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}", str))
```

Output

```
['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '68f74d66-ca3d-4272-9b59-4f737946b3f7', '138bb190-3b12-4855-88e2-0d1cdf46aeb5']
```

Comment: I've been wrestling with `regex` module for a good hour now. Couldn crack it. Well done. I kept looking at `\G` options but I am too unexperienced to make that work. +

Comment: @JvdV If you want to use the `\G` you have to find a way to get continuous matches using the position at the end of the previous match. One option could be https://regex101.com/r/Yme3VZ/1. Chances are that this pattern can be simplified :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `re` module in Python then maybe use `str.startwith` and try:

```
import re
url="/transfer/packages/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/connectors/68f74d66-ca3d-4272-9b59-4f737946b3f7/something/138bb190-3b12-4855-88e2-0d1cdf46aeb5/...../...../...../...../...."
if url.startswith('/transfer/packages/'):
    Guid_List = re.findall(r'(?i)[a-z0-9]{8}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){3}-[a-z0-9]{12}', url)
print(Guid_List)
```

Comment: Thank you, however the `url=""` is itself part of the string to search into, I guess that's not clear from my original post, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915380/7629560):

> As for the second question, it is a common problem. It is not possible to get an arbitrary number of captures with a PCRE regex, as in case of repeated captures only the last captured value is stored in the group buffer. You cannot have more submatches in the resulting array than the number of capturing groups inside the regex pattern. See Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group for more details.

Comment: I understand. So the only generic way would be to do it in two steps, right?

Comment: I don't know if that could be accomplished with two steps. The recursion can be done with two steps, but in PCRE it only captures a group as a whole and does not split them.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting to know.